# Recently installed ubuntu 15.04 replacing Windows 7, on Thinkpad Edge E430. Sound issue

Tags: sound, thinkpad

I had a Dolby software for speakers on Windows 7, and it worked well. Sound on Ubuntu is weak. Anything that is amiss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> copy past this to it

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

this will install a number of tools in your PC.

open the hda-jack-retask then do the following.

```
Select the IDT 92HD91BXX codec (may be different on other models; but definately other than your on-board controller i.e., Intel-XXX).
Check the “Show unconnected pins” box (the internal speakers do not show as connected)
Remap 0x0d (Internal Speaker, which is your Front side) to “Internal speaker”
Remap 0x0f (“Not connected”, which is the under-display speakers) to “Internal speaker”
Remap 0×10 (“Not connected”, which is the subwoofer) to “Internal speaker (LFE)”
Apply & test audio output with any media player.
Select “Install boot override” to save the settings to apply at boot time.
Reboot. When it comes back, you should have full sound from all speakers. Also test headphones. Plugging in headphones should disable sound from all internal speakers.
```

Comment: hi @ronniedroid. i have installed alsa and speakers work. but they were glorious on windows ! thanks.

Comment: So if ma answer helped, please vote-up and mark it as the right question :D. happy it did help you